# Developing with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I've heard  a lot of the Phonegap framework and starting to dig into it soon.

As far as I've understood Phonegap allows you to create Web applications that is converted to a native mobile app.

However my questions is how do I use database ? fx SQL lite?  If it is only HTML5, CSS3 and Java script then how is this possible?  What if I want to use let's say access to the phone book? How is this accomplished?

Or if I want to use something else that is part of the Android SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would go through with the documentation files many things could have been clear already.

1) There are 3 kinds of database in phonegap. `localStorage`, `webSQL`, `indexedDB`. If you want to use `SQLite` then there are SQLite wrappers which allow you to create and maintain SQLite database from javascript

2) Yes it's html,css,javascript. They are main weapons. But you can also use native codes to accomplish some task which can't be done with web technology only. There is a system called custom plugin. You can build custom plugin to use native codes if you need.

3) Most of the things are already taken care of by phonegap. Stuff like using contacts, playing media etc. can be done using various api. These are called plugin. If you install contact plugin, you will be able to use contact list using javascript code. ([See this example for how it's done](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.find))

Basically phonegap gives you a framework which acts like a bridge between web technology and native technology.

Comment: Perfect. Now it seems more clear. Thank you very much!